# mysql bulk update performance when `WHERE` filter is not satisfied

Tags: mysql, bulkupdate

bulk update like this:

```
update table_name set price='x1' where sku='x1'; #updated because sku=x1 exist
update table_name set price='x2' where sku='x2'; #ignored because sku=x2 does not exist
update table_name set price='x3' where sku='x3'; #ignored because sku=x2 does not exist
  ...about 10000 lines...
```

some lines did not update anything because they do not exist, I want to know, would they make mysql slow OR just affect nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an index on `sku`, then the `updates` should have reasonable performance.  If they are in a single transaction, then the performance should be okay.

However, you would be better off putting the new data into a table and using a `join` for the `update`.

Comment: `update table_name as t1 left join table_name as t2 on t1.id=t2.id set t1.price='x1' where t2.sku='x1'`,  you mean that?

Comment: @Mil0r . . . Use `join` not `left join`.  You only want the values that match.